# Facebook API - Required param "state" missing from persistent data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know that this question is a duplicate of another, however after searching Google and Stack Overflow, I have still yet to find a solution.

I have some code which calls the Facebook API for a login URL.  However, I am doing it in a somewhat indirect way.  Basically here is the server flow:

1. Client chooses to login to app with FB
2. Client website (A) sends HTTP GET request to intermediate website (B)
3. Website B returns login URL on website B which includes 2 callbacks: a login URL to FB generated with fb->getLoginUrl() and a callback to website A.
4. Website A redirects to login page on Website B which redirects to login page on FB
5. User logs in and grants permissions to app on FB website
6. FB redirects to callback on website B which gets the access code.
7. Website B redirects to Website A callback passing the access code as a $_GET variable
8. Website A uses the access token as it wishes

So very complicated and I only include the flow to possibly make answering this question and understanding the code in PHP easier.

PHP
Website A Code:

```
if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $callback = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $request_url = "http://embocorp.com/factory/api.php/facebook/login?callback=".$callback;
  header("Location: ".implode(json_decode(callAPI("GET", $request_url), true)['body']['data']));
} else {
  echo $_GET['code'];
}
```

Website B Code:
api.php

```
if (!session_id()) {
  session_start();
}

require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));
$input = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
$table = array_shift($request);
$key = array_shift($request);
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query_array);

$callback = "http://embocorp.com/factory/api.php/facebook/callback?call=";

function returnData($data, $options = "") {      
  $response = [
    "data"=>$data
  ];
  return json_encode($response, $options);
}
function getFacebookConnection($appid, $appsecret) {
  return new Facebook\Facebook(['app_id' => $appid,'app_secret' => $appsecret,'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',    'persistent_data_handler'=>'session']);
}
function facebookHandleRequest($request, $connection, $details = null) {
  switch($request) {
    case "login":
      $callback_url = $GLOBALS["callback"].$GLOBALS['query_array']['callback'];
      echo returnData("http://embocorp.com/factory/login.php?fb=".getFacebookLoginURL($connection, $callback_url), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
      break;
    case "callback":
      if (!empty($GLOBALS["query_array"])) {
        foreach ($_COOKIE as $k=>$v) {
          if(strpos($k, "FBRLH_")!==FALSE) {
            $_SESSION[$k]=$v;
          }
        }
        $access = getFacebookAccessCode($connection);
        $called = $GLOBALS['query_array']['called'];
        header("location: ".$called."?code=".$access);
      } else {
        echo returnError(400, "Bad Request, missing authorization");
      }
      break;
    case "me":
      if (!empty($GLOBALS["query_array"]) &&  array_key_exists("accessToken", $GLOBALS["query_array"]) == true) {
        $response = $connection->sendRequest('GET', '/me', [], $GLOBALS["query_array"]["accessToken"], 'eTag', 'v2.2');
        $user = $response->getGraphUser();
        echo returnData($user);
      } else {
        echo returnError(400, "Bad Request, missing authorization");
      }
      break;
    default:
      echo returnError(404, "Request URI Not Found");
      break;
  }
}
function getFacebookLoginURL($connection, $callback_url) {
  $helper = $connection->getRedirectLoginHelper();
  $permissions = ['manage_pages', 'publish_pages', 'read_insights'];
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback_url, $permissions);
  foreach ($_SESSION as $k=>$v) {                    
    if(strpos($k, "FBRLH_")!==FALSE) {
      if(setcookie($k, $v)) {
        $_COOKIE[$k]=$v;
      }
    }
  }
  return $loginUrl;
}
function getFacebookAccessCode($fb){
  if (!session_id()) {
    $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    return $accessToken;
  } else {
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    try {
      $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }
    if (isset($accessToken)) {
      $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
      return (string) $accessToken;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
} 

switch ($table) {
  case "facebook":
    $fb = getFacebookConnection($appid, $appsecret);
    facebookHandleRequest($key, $fb);
    break;
  case "twitter":
    echo "no";
    break;
  default:
    exit();
    break;
}

session_write_close();

?>
```

login.php

```
if (!session_id()) {
  session_start();
}
if (isset($_GET['fb'])) {
  $redirect = str_replace("fb=", "", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  header("Location: ".$redirect);
} else {
  echo "ni";
}
```

Again, thank you for any help, this has been driving me crazy for 72 hours now.

Comment: Where are you performing the step of exchanging the code for an access token? Since you created the login URL under domain B, you will have to do that on B too, since the state value is stored in the session of domain B.

Comment: I do it on domain B.  Login.php goes to facebook which then goes back to api.php to exchange the code for access token.

Comment: Then check if your session (on B) works properly - do you get the same session id before and after?

Comment: Yes I tested that already.  The session id and even that FLBH_state (I think that's what its called) is the same before and after

Comment: If you say you are handling all the relevant parts of the login flow on domain B – then why is there a check for a GET parameter `code` in your script on A?

Comment: Because when I get the access code on B I will pass the code via the GET parameter code to Website A

Comment: What for? What does A need the code for, if B handles all the login stuff? B should return the access token to A.

Comment: First, the code that is being passed to Website A refers to the accesstoken.  I actually fixed it.  Instead of redirecting the user from Website A to the login.php on Website B I just redirected Website A to api.php/facebook/login on Website B which took care of everything and sent the token back to A.  The problem was that the redirection to FB was being done on a page separate from the one that generated the URL.

Comment: Yes, the `redirect_uri` parameter value used in the API call to exchange the code for a token must match the one that was used in the login dialog call.

Answer (score -1):

Just add,

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
```

in start both file.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: @Peter Sorry for that,
here is how i find my solution,
[from this disccusion](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/issues/473)

I find that facebook-php-graph-sdk is using session. and i tried session_start(), and it's work